# PhpStorm not removing duplicate "use" (imports)

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have the following class header, which is the result of a merge in source control. In PhpStorm, when I go I use **code>optimize imports**, the imports aren't really optimized... there are duplicate import statements which seems silly to me (see second code block below). Why can't PhpStorm clean this up? Am I missing an option or feature to do this?

Before "**optimize imports**"...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tool\Models;
use App\Tool\Models\UserId;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Repository\IUserRepository;
use Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Eloquent\User;
use App\Repository\IUserRepository;
use Auth;
use Input;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Log;

class UserController extends Controller
```

after "**optimize imports**"...

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Repository\IUserRepository;
use App\Repository\IUserRepository;
use Input;
use Input;
use Log;

class UserController extends Controller
```

Comment: FWIW, I prefer to handle use clauses by hand as that makes one think more about how you actually use them in code, and it’s easier to categorise them and such :)